How to save data the most efficient
If I have a lot of data to save, say 500 ints for how many stars a user has collected, some text for user created levels, settings, etc.
What would be the best method to save all of this?
Should I use a lot of PlayerPrefs and give them names so Stars might be "Level/StarsCollected/A3" or a level would be "Editor/CreatedLevels/1"
Should I create a file for each topic, so afile for editor, a file for Stars, one for unlocked skins etc.
Should I store all in one single big file and load it into RAM when game bootup?

What are the ranges of the Ints, and are there negative numbers? The optimal storage is in a binary file.  This format allows for fixed data sizes for each variable, optimizing the storage size with minimal impact on loading speeds. Note that unlocking skins is a single bit in an unsigned (32 or 64 bit) bit-field(s).

"Best" depends on what you're trying to optimize. A compressed format reduces size, but takes a more resources to compress & decompress. A human readable format is easy to make quick on the fly hand edits to as you're developing the game, but typically takes more storage space. What format are you currently using  and what problems are you having? If you don't yet have a format, what would you like / intend to use & what are your concerns?

It will depend as well if this is an online game with external storage, local game only, how much you care about if the user starts manipulating save data and how much backwards compatible you want to be.

I made some more research and settled on the following: I will use Player prefs for insensible things, like settins, selected skin, trail etc. I will use a json file for the created levels, if the user manipulates those it doesn't do anything he could not do in the editor. For completed levels, stars etc. I will try to implement a binary file format. Thanks for helping!

One last Question though: When I save in json for example, do I need to name the file xxx.json or can I just name it xxx so the user doesn't know what file type this is, which may make it a littlr bit more secure? I am using Unity JsonUtility to read and write files.

You dont need to use .json at the end but since it is a default file format, it will/ should still open in plain text when the user uses as much as a texteditor like notepad. The file ending in most cases just tells your operating system with which program the file should be opened

Cool, Thanks for answering!
